# AD provisioning says that "A required attribute is missing from a response", but it does exist in the response

Tags: active-directory, scim

I'm working on implementing SCIM 2.0, as I need to use to to provision users in my system that are stored in Azure AD.  I have set it up and when I try to manually provision a user, I get this error:

[image: active directory error]

The user is successfully provisioned on the client side, as you might guess from the error message - it's not an issue with the request.

I am guessing that the issue is with *where* the identifier is located, since the `Identifier` attribute is included in the response that is in the error message.

I've googled this error and I can find general tutorials for AD SCIM implementations, but I haven't been able to find anything about this specific error.

Here's a pretty-printed version of the response:

```json
{
  "totalResults": 1,
  "startIndex": 0,
  "itemsPerPage": 1,
  "schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse"
  ],
  "Resources": [
    {
      "emails": [
        {
          "type": "work",
          "value": "perrin@***.com",
          "primary": true
        }
      ],
      "Identifier": "1072",
      "meta": {
        "meta": "/scim/v2/Users/1072",
        "resourceType": "User"
      },
      "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"
      ],
      "name": {
        "familyName": "Aybara",
        "givenName": "Perrin"
      },
      "active": true,
      "id": "1072",
      "userName": "perrin@***.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it the issue was not that the resources were missing anything - it was the `ListResponse` itself that needed an ID.  If I include

```
"id": "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse"
```

to the top-level object (along with `totalResults`, etc.) it is processed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

•   As you are provisioning a user manually through SCIM functionality of Azure AD, the issuer identity, i.e., Azure AD is identified by an iss claim in the token received after successfully provisioning the user from Azure AD. Example of it is as below: -

```
"iss":https://sts.windows.net/cbb1a5ac-f33b-45fa-9bf5-f37db0fed422/
```

where ‘https://sts.windows.net’ is the URL of the issuer, i.e., Azure AD and the ‘cbb1a5ac-f33b-45fa-9bf5-f37db0fed422’ is the unique identifier of the Azure AD tenant for which it was issued. This token was issued for the application template ID of the app configured for provisioning in enterprise applications.

•   Also, please note that the query to provision an Azure AD user with the ‘create’ action in the client app web service with an ‘externalId’ attribute value that matches the ‘mailNickname’ attribute value of a user doesn't return any users in your case as shown in the image, then AAD requests that the web service provision a user corresponding to the one in AAD. The user provisioned from Azure AD is assigned an identifier value when the provisioning succeeds and returns an instance of the Microsoft.SCIM.Core2EnterpriseUser class with identifier attribute indicating the user provisioned. Thus, since the user identifier value is missing as shown in the image, please run the below command to query whether the user is created successfully or not.

```
‘ GET ~/scim/Users/54D382A4-2050-4C03-94D1-E769F1D15682 HTTP/1.1
 Authorization: Bearer ... ’
```

In a request to retrieve the current state of the user provisioned, the values of the properties of the object provided as the value of the parameters argument are as follows:

```
  Identifier: "54D382A4-2050-4C03-94D1-E769F1D15682"
  SchemaIdentifier: "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"
```

•   Request you to try again to provision the user and query to request the current state of the user regarding its reference attribute. Also, send a request from Azure AD to the SCIM service to update the user in its datastore. Here is an example of the request sent from Azure AD to the SCIM service: -

```
  ‘ PATCH ~/scim/Users/54D382A4-2050-4C03-94D1-E769F1D15682 HTTP/1.1
    Authorization: Bearer ...
    Content-type: application/scim+json
   {
       "schemas": 
   [
  "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"],
"Operations":
[
  {
    "op":"Add",
    "path":"manager",
    "value":
      [
        {
          "$ref":"http://.../scim/Users/2819c223-7f76-453a-919d-413861904646",
          "value":"2819c223-7f76-453a-919d-413861904646"}]}]} ‘
```

Please find the detailed steps in the link as below: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups#handling-provisioning-and-deprovisioning-of-users

Comment: As mentioned in the question I have confirmed that the user is being successfully created in the target system. The only issue seems to be with the *format* of the response that my service is sending back to AD. The link you provided includes some example response formats (such as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups#response-4) but I am not seeing a specific example for the above response, which is a ListResult.

Comment: The core schema in SCIM as defined has only three important mandatory attributes, they are id, username and meta of which all three are present in your response except the meta which doesn't have the created and last modified value in your response due to which your service provider may be unable to determine the creation of a user.

Comment: This answer didn't give me the information that I needed, but I was able eventually to resolve the issue and I have posted the resolution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally shows up when there is something invalid with the format of the JSON payload. From looking at this one, I suspect it's your inclusion of "Identifier" as this is not defined in the core SCIM schema docs, and specifically may be causing issues if it overlaps with something else in the provisioning service. "id" is the correct attribute to use.

Comment: This fails with or without the Identifier included. Initially I included on the "id" and added the Identifier when the error message seemed to indicate that it was needed.